# VSTS Deploy with git push to a remote repository

Tags: git, deployment, azure-devops, release

I'm currently working with VSTS to host a git repository containing a WordPress site. I want to push this repository to a remote (wpengine) using SSH. I'm currently failing to see how to do this and having little success in building a release which can do this - there aren't any guides and the documentation for the plugins which look helpful here aren't very complete. Is there inbuilt functionality in VSTS release to allow this?

Comment: How about using wrapper script? https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/how-to-specify-an-ssh-key-file-with-the-git-command/ (option 2)

Comment: Do you use private agent? The easy way is that you can configure ssh in local, then change private agent service account to your account, after that you can call `git push ssh//` command to push changes to remote repository, otherwise, you need to specify the private key file through ssh-add command.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT thanks, that&#39;s a good idea actually I have resource to setup a private agent.

Comment: Try to configure ssh manually and make sure you can clone and push code through SSH, then change agent service account to your account and restart the service.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT brilliant advice, I guess I could do this in some sort of bootstrapping script for new agents too. Is there no way to do this from the vsts agents (the ones already setup in Azure I presume)

Comment: By default it uses the private key file that in `C:\Users\{service account}\.ssh`, so you need to specify the private key file (e.g. call ssh-add command, may need to call start-ssh-agent.cmd firstly) or copy the private key file to that folder through command line task (simple way is copy file to .ssh folder).

Comment: I think you need to specify or copy the known_hosts file too.

Comment: What's the result now?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I'll give this a test tonight, unfortunately I've been away, apologies for the delay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My work flow is to push up into a remote repository and pull down, ssh'd into your site. This always for you to commit back to a working version of your staging/production site if a bug is caught, it allows for a workflow where a pull request can be issued and reviewed if necessary and of course, a single point, where code can be reverted if necessary.

Here is my paraphrased workflow:

### Create your own personal token on vsts.

These are the instructions: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate

1. Click on your personnel icon(top right corner) on vsts.
2. Click on **Security**
3. Click on **Personnel Access tokens**
4. Click on Add new
5. Save the generated token

### Create Alternate Authentication credentials

1. Click personnel icon(top right corner) on vsts
2. Click on **Security**
3. Click on **Alternate authentication credentials**
4. Make sure you fill in the ‘User name (secondary)’, this will be part of your security code

### SSH TIME

1. Open Putty or ssh client
2. Type ‘cd html’ (this is where go daddy is stored)
3. Type ‘git init’
4. Type ‘git fetch remote https://(usernamesecondary):(personalaccesstokencode)@~~~~~.visualstudio.com/GitcloneUrl . .
   Or
   'git remote add salessite https://(usernamesecondary):(personalaccesstokencode)@~~~~~.visualstudio.com/GitcloneUrl .'

**salessite is the name of the repo

5. 'git pull salessite'
6. 'git checkout –f branchname'

Be sure to have the ending period(.) as this will fill in the contents of the directory without the directory name.

Hope this is helpful. I working on a tutorial for using Visual Studio git setup coming up.